# Submit file to a remote form from Unity which doesn't have a form action

Tags: c#, forms, unity-game-engine

I want to submit a form with a file input from my Unity game using C#. However, the [form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwyLFk3yeLS8ZtHsfET7ms89RqHuHrE3Kjozt2e4dxk47EmTX0/exec) doesn't have an action and is seemingly submitted via script. I know how to submit data to a form which has a form action associated to it (using `WWWForm`). But, how do I submit the data to such a form without an action associated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to submit this form, just find out this form's submitted url and posted data and file fieldName.

Make a unity WWWForm request with adding AddField for data and AddBinaryData for file.

Comment: But I can't find the form's submitted url from the link above, can you?

Comment: I got this one [link](https://n-lhuyk2yfwdifcndaomkb46ivltmzoasziz62aei-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com)

Comment: I observed this url getting fired in the network tab, but it didnt work either https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwyLFk3yeLS8ZtHsfET7ms89RqHuHrE3Kjozt2e4dxk47EmTX0/callback?nocache_id=3